# GLFW Undefined References using Eclipse + MinGW on Windows 8

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows-8, glfw

I am trying to set up GLFW. I am working in Eclipse CDT on Windows 8.1

I have downloaded the GLFW binaries and am trying to run the example code here http://www.glfw.org/documentation.html

So far I have included the glfw header and I am linking (statically) with glfw3, opengl32 and gdi32 (in that order).

The compiler is running the following commands

```
g++ "-IC:\\Libraries\\GLFW3\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o main.o "..\\main.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\\Libraries\\GLFW3\\lib-mingw" -o HelloGLFW3.exe main.o -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lgdi32
```

I get the error "Undefined reference to ..." for each of the GLFW functions.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I have done a Google search and there were some similar questions asked on Stack Overflow but none of them solved the problems. The most common suggestion is to re-order the linking order but as far as I can tell the order is correct, and I tried it just in case but it made no difference.

Can anyone provide instruction on how to link correctly?

EDIT: I've tried it with both the 32bit and 64bit glfw binaries (My original attempt was with the 64 bit binaries but Google said that it may be a problem trying to link 32 bit and 64 bit programs - from what I can tell my version of MinGW can only produce 32 bit outputs). These are the errors that are produced:

64bit binaries:

```
undefined reference to `glfwCreateWindow'   main.cpp    /HelloGLFW3 line 12 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `glfwInit'
undefined reference to `glfwMakeContextCurrent'
undefined reference to `glfwPollEvents'
undefined reference to `glfwSwapBuffers'
undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
undefined reference to `glfwTerminate'
undefined reference to `glfwWindowShouldClose'
```

32bit binaries:

```
undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16' HelloGLFW3      line 0, external location: C:\Libraries\GLFW3\i386\lib-mingw\libglfw3.a(win32_gamma.c.obj):win32_gamma.c    C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `_imp__CreateDCW@16'
undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'
undefined reference to `_imp__DeleteDC@4'
undefined reference to `_imp__DescribePixelFormat@16'
undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceCaps@8'
undefined reference to `_imp__GetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
undefined reference to `_imp__SetDeviceGammaRamp@8'
undefined reference to `_imp__SetPixelFormat@12'
undefined reference to `_imp__SwapBuffers@4'
```

Comment: I assume you did put the downloaded binaries into your `lib-mingw` folder, right? Which package did you download exactly?

Comment: I downloaded the 64bit windows binaries. It came with the include files and the libraries for mingw and msvc compilers; so yes, the libraries are in the lib-mingw folder.

Comment: Ok, I downloaded them also and see the structure. Can you please post one "unresolved reference" error message, so I can see which kind of symbol he tries to resolve, please?

Comment: Hm, just did a fresh installation of MinGW and wrote test code that calls `glfwInit()` and `glfwCreateWindow()`, using the command line you have posted. Works fine. Have you tried deleting the *.a files and link against the DLL?

Comment: I'm an idiot, when I swaped to the 32bit binaries of GLFW I accidentaly removed the -lgdi32 tag and that was what was causing the link error. The original problem was that I was using 64bit GLFW libraries and the GNU compiler was producing a 32bit output of my program. Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

GLFW provides both 64bit and 32bit binary versions. When you compile your program you can produce either a 64bit output or a 32bit output. Your program has to be compatible with with the libraries that you are using.

This means that just because you have a 64bit computer doesn't mean you need the 64bit binaries. Also it's a good idea to check that your compiler is outputting what you think it is outputting.